# Generic constraints on own type

Tags: c#

I want to write a generic class that has generic constraints :

```
public class MyClass<TokenType> where TokenType : IComparable, IComparable<TokenType>, IEquatable<TokenType>;
```

Well, it works fine.

But... I decide to create an interface to give a name to this constraints list and the best I can do is:

```
public class MyClass<TokenType> where TokenType : ITokenable;
public interface ITokenable : IComparable, IComparable<ITokenable>, IEquatable<ITokenable>;
```

But I don't want a RealToken class to be IComparable to any ITokenable, but only RealToken, so I add contraints.

```
public class MyClass<TokenType> where TokenType : ITokenable<TokenType>;
public interface ITokenable<T> : IComparable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T> where T : ITokenable<T>;
```

However, when implementing a new RealToken class, it gives

```
public class RealToken : ITokenable<RealToken>;
```

1/ It would be great to not have to specify my own class as generic constraint

2/ Nothing prevent me at compile time to create a such class which has no sens:

```
public class RealToken : ITokenable<AnotherToken>;
```

Is there a way to write the constraints cascade whitout ambiguity ?

Comment: Short answer: no. C# does not support "anchored" generics. In practice, the ability to do it "wrong" is not a concern -- this is not the sort of thing someone gets wrong "accidentally" and then fails to notice when the class doesn't work. While the redundancy is a bit less elegant, it's redundancy on a single line of code, so that's not a terrible burden either. (It's certainly not worth working around with, say, code generation of some sort, unless the classes are already generated, though code snippets are an option.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact, I have a CS0314 if I replace MyClass contraints by "ITokenable<TokenType" without the tree others interfaces. So I will not create ITokenable at all...

Comment: This is called the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, and is an old problem in generics. There is no other workaround in C#. If C# had a `this` constraint which constrains the `T` parameter to be the same as the defining class, that would be a different story, but it doesn't unfortunately